# Connect failed on MX record lookup - what does that mean?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server

I'm trying to work out why I'm getting an error message when testing my MX DNS:

[image]

Here is what I have set for it:

```
mail    139.162.248.70
mail    2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fed5:3319
```

Why would I get an error message? I can send emails to them fine, but the client is saying that they have people complaining of the emails bouncing. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:** I just heard back from the client, that the people trying to contact him were using the wrong email address! So false alarm. However, I would still be interested to know what the "Connect failed" message is all about?

Comment: probably an issue with the testing website itself? Testing your domain from here returned all OK, and exactly the same IPs you mentioned

Comment: @WaleedHamra ahhh ok thanks, it just had me panicking, as otherwise it all seemed to be working fine :) Thanks for the clarification

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Wtdjqi7m  these are my results :)

Comment: The two IPs you give do not seem to be reachable on port 25 (SMTP). The v4 one just timeouts, and the v6 gives immediately "connection refused".

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Interesting. Is there any reason it should allow port 25? I say that, because we are sending out via a secure connection, and my understanding is that port 25 if the not secure port for emails?

Comment: If you define a MX record with a name resolving to the above IP adresses, it means the computer having those adresses is expected to *receive* email from outside for the domain name considered, and hence it has to listen on port 25 where the SMTP protocol will work.

Comment: Ah ok weird - well I have 25,465,587,2525 set as open on my firewall, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be connecting (we can certainly send out emails OK from the server)